# ipad/iphone: hide keyboard when user taps anywhere else on the screen

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisearchbar

I have a situation,

I have some searchbar on same screen when i click on a search bar keyboard appears. Now is it possible that this keyboard disappears if we click any where else on the scree.

Please help me with this.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution is here

http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitextfield-tutorial-handling-keyboard-interactions/

for tableView you can all the same method in didSelectRow method

Comment: This doesn't work if you are tapping inside a UIScrollView. For that case you should subclass UIScrollView and override the - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event method and resignFirstResponder on whatever the first responder is.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a pretty elegant solution of this task:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
- (void)dismissKeyboard
{
   [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

// dismiss keyboard through `resignFirstResponder`

}
```

Comment: control is not going to this method itself, tried putting break point in this

Comment: Is the view a viewController's view?

Comment: I think the tableview cells are absorbing the touch.

Comment: did u try this method in the class of the custom table view?

Answer (score 0):

You need the UI field to resign the first responder status to dismiss the keyboard.

```
[field resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: from which method I can resign first responder

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what AlBlue and 7KV7 said, normally you'll have some UIView over which the keyboard pops up, and generally it's okay to click in that to "remove focus" from the input field. I.e. it's more elaborate to detect clicks "everywhere outside the field and keyboard popup", such as on the toolbar or navigation bar that has the field, a button in a tableview, etc.

So to avoid handling any views that could "eat up" touches that could be on your UIView, the best way could be to add a transparent view vertically above the keyboard popup, to your app's Window.

If you have a scrollview, do something like this (pasted working code) since it seems scrollview specifically don't invoke touchesBegan.

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    UITextField *tfCount=(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:335];
    [tfCount resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

It's handy to tag the input field's view unless you keep a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the search bar, it gains the focus and become the first responder. So, the problem is when to release the focus by resignFirstResponder method. Generally, I will make a transparent button in the front for detecting any touch on the screen exclusive of the search bar. Or, you can register a gesture recognizer to receive a tap event and release the keyboard focus.

About gesture recognizer, you can refer to [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009279) about UIGestureRecognizer. It is available in iOS 3.2 and later. So, iPad app can use this kind of classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
        [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```